# Css3 device-width and orientation change

Tags: html, css

I'd like the background color to change while changing orientation. I have the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
...

@media all and (max-device-width: 360px) {
  div { background-color: green; } }      

@media all and (min-device-width: 361px) {
  div { background-color: blue; } }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. But when i change `max-device-width` and `min-device-width` to `max-width` and `min-width` it works.
Why the code with `max-device-width` and `min-device-width` isn't working?

Comment: may I ask where did you use these code then?

Comment: @nire i'm afraid you aren't right. When i change device orientation on my android phone `screen.width` changes from 360px in portrait position to 640px in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

Add this to your HTML Page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And to your css code you have to add:

```
div {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {

  div{
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

So when the window width is under 360 Pixel, the background-color will change to green, otherwise it will be blue.

Answer (score 0):

Because it has to know that it is a device by displaying it. So it excludes all desktop visibility.

I would recommend not using this because not all device browsers send a recognition that the content is viewed on a device making it unpredictable when your design is applied.

Stick to min-width and height it is saver.

Comment: "Because it has to know that it is a device by displaying it. So it excludes all desktop visibility. " Can You please clarify this statement?

Comment: with device i mean mobile phones or tablets